# Can't change screen brightness in applicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, brightness

My app gives the user the possibility to change the screen brightness and after the app is terminated i want to restore the initial brightness whenn the app was started.

I use applicationWillTerminate as my app opts out of multitasking and thus is terminated instead of moved to background when the home button is pressed.

The issue: `[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = self.brightnessAfterLaunch` is completely ignored when called in applicationWillTerminate and the system brightness is at the previously set brightness within the app after termination. (NOT the brightness  before the app was started!)

Why is this igrnored or is there any other way to restore the previous system brightness?

Answer (score 0):

I change the screen brightness back to the start value in

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;

which gets called when the user presses the home button.